# How can Watney get so much hydrogen in the air?

Tags: mars, the-martian

This does not make sense to me.

Mark Watney needs water. He uses an iridium dish to decompose hydrazine into a gaseous mix of hydrogen and nitrogen (2:1 ratio) that he feeds into a hand made oven. Exact quote: "Soon I had short bursts of flame sputtering from the chimney." For some reason, hydrogen does not fully combust and contaminates the air.
In the end there is seven times more the hydrogen in the air than oxygen (64% volume).
It should have exploded when reached 4% concentration.

Also, there is a lot of nitrogen generated at the iridium dish, yet nitrogen is only at 22% in the end, even though part of hydrogen is utilized to produce water

One more thing, he produces hundreds of liters of water from CO2 (via regenerated O2), but it should have produced about 100kg of carbon - where did it go to? How does his oxidizer work? I haven't read beyond this point so I wonder if he had an idea to feed that carbon to his plants.

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81274/how-was-mav-fuel-plant-able-to-make-fuel-using-hydrogen-so-quickly-in-the-end?

Comment: Richard, no, this is very different. This one is almost in the beginning, and it's about water, not fuel

Comment: Fair enough. I've not read it, it just seemed similar.

Comment: He doesn't need to do anything with the carbon, as the scrubber handles it and presumably discards it in some way (vents to the outside?) - the job of the scrubber is to remove excess CO2 from the air and extract the O2 from it - Watney uses it to remove excess O2 from the air as well at some point in the book, so it also can manage the exact atmosphere mix.

Comment: Moo, are you trying to say that the oxidizer vents solid carbon out? I have read to the point where he collects O2 from the air, but we can be sure that this is a gradual process. So it can't just jump from zero to 60%

Comment: What does "he" refer to?

Comment: The protagonist. The one he keeps calling "I".

Comment: The protagonist has no name?

Comment: I'm sure he does, but I don't see how it is relevant

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit, making the question have some sense for people unfamiliar with the story.

Comment: SQB, I added some more info

Comment: Check the *Lithium Hydroxide* section here, regarding the CO2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber
"Lithium peroxide can also be used as it absorbs more CO2 per unit weight with the added advantage of releasing oxygen". Regarding the H2 and O2 balance, do I remember correctly that he intended there be essentially no extra O2 in the air inside, but he forgot about his O2 mask leaking extra O2 around his face? His intention was to control the H2 combustion by starving the O2 needed for combustion. Theoretically he could have 100% H2 and 0% O2 and there would be no combustion.

Comment: Todd, no, my question is about his hydrogen-burning oven

Answer (score 7):

You have confused "explosive mixture" with "exploding mixture". The explosive mixture range for a hydrogen/air mixture is 4% to 75%. However, just because a substance is explosive does not mean that it will spontaneously explode. In the case of hydrogen, a spark or flame is required, and presumably Watney is producing neither. Apparently, high-pressure hydrogen jets can self-ignite, but that does not apply. Likewise, there are reports that hydrogen-air mixtures can self-ignite in the presence of a catalyst such as platinum, but that does not seem appropriate either.

The autoignition temperature for hydrogen is 500 C, so as long as Watney does not provide an open flame or produce sparks, and has no local temperatures in excess of 500 C, he is theoretically safe.

That said, I'd be **very** surprised if there were not spark sources such as ventilation motors in his habitat.

Comment: If you read the book you would know that he was burning his hydrogen using an open fire.

Answer (score 2):

Just because the hydrogen has the capability to combust, does not mean it will do so without provocation.

Hydrogen needs a spark or an open flame to be ignited, unless it reaches 500 C, which, as Watney was still alive, we can assume it didn't.

The hydrogen that was in the air seperated from the group *before* reaching the flame provided by Watney, and there was a constant flow of O2 there preventing the Hydrogen from combusting on it.

The reason that the hydrogen content is so low is because of the Atmospheric Regulator, a wonderful piece of technology that has the capability to freeze separate the air in the Hab.

> The regulator uses freezeseparation
>   to sort out the
>   gasses. When it decides
>   there’s too much oxygen, it
>   starts collecting air in a tank
>   and cooling it to 90 kelvin.
>   That makes the oxygen turn
>   to liquid, but leaves the
>   nitrogen (condensation point:
>   77K) still gaseous. Then it
>   stores the O2 **- Mark Watney - The Martian**
>   .

So this is why the Hydrogen content was so high whilst the O2 and N2 concentrations remained within normality.
Note that he could *not* do this with the hydrogen as it's freeze temperature is much too low.

The way he turned the CO2 into pure O2 is a bit more complicated, however.

The AR (Atmospheric Regulator) stores the CO2 into tanks, which then go to the Oxygenator, a fancy device which takes CO2, liberates the O2, and vents the remainder (carbon) outside.

Comment: 1. "hydrogen that was in the air seperated from the group before reaching the flame" - can you elaborate on that? 2. "vents the remainder (carbon) outside" by carbon you mean graphite?

Comment: By that quote I'd meant to say that the hydrogen that was left over was from the Iridium plate, not from being pumped (gravity fed, really) into the flame with the O2 pouring, since the flame was sort of protected by the flow provided by the liquid O2, the hydrogen didn't combust, and there is no canon explanation, but graphite would seem to be a likely byproduct which could easily be dealt with via crushing it into a powder, or if it were already a powder just simply fanning it out.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you here.